# Powershell: retrive DB properties, convert sizes in percentage and formatting to send a mail report

Tags: sql-server, powershell, formatting, report, converters

I've a working script (wrote by an ex-colleague) that connects to mssql db, gets the size of each db and reports them in to csv file using a logging and formatting technique that I don't understand.

This is the relevant lines:

```bsh
$reportcsv = $((get-location).path + "\Results\result-size.csv")

Out-File -FilePath $reportcsv -InputObject $("srvname;Db.Name;TotalDBSize;dbSize;LogSize;DbUsedSpace;LogUsedSpace")

foreach ($Server in $icmDBServers)
    {

    $logstring = "Connessione DB " + $Server.Name
    WriteLog -OutFile $LogFile -Type info -text $logString -prompt $true
    
    $DBConnection = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
    $DBConnection.ServerInstance=$Server.Name
    
    $ServerObj = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server($DBConnection)

    
    if (----Param cmd condition----)
        {
        "############################################################################################"
        "{0,-28}{1,64}" -f "##","#"
        "####### {0,-28}      {1,11} {2,38}   " -f  "S E R V E R   N A M E", $Server.Name, "########"
        "{0,-28}{1,64}" -f "##","#"
        "############################################################################################"
        foreach ($db in $ServerObj.Databases)
            {
            switch ($db.Name )
                {   
                "master" {} 
                "model"  {}
                "msdb"   {}
                default 
                        {
                        $logstring = ""                 
                        $LogUsedSpace = [System.Math]::Round($($db.LogFiles | measure-object -property UsedSpace -sum).sum/1024,2)
                        $LogSize = [System.Math]::Round($($db.LogFiles | measure-object -property Size -sum).sum/1024,2)
                        $TotalDBSize = [System.Math]::Round($db.Size,2)
                        $dbSize = [System.Math]::Round($db.Size - $logsize,2)
                        $DbUsedSpace = [System.Math]::Round($db.Size - $db.SpaceAvailable/1024,2)
                        $DBUsageP = $($DbUsedSpace / $TotalDBSize)
                        $LogUsageP = $($LogUsedSpace / $LogSize)
                        #"{0,-28} {1,12}  ########" -f  "####### DB SIZE REPORT for DATABASE ", $db.Name
                        "{0,-28} {1,50} ###" -f "#######  DB SIZE REPORT for DATABASE ", $db.Name
                        "{0,-28}{1,64}" -f "##","#"
                        "{0,-28} {1,12}    MB {2,44} " -f "DB TotalSize", $TotalDBSize ,"#"
                        "{0,-28} {1,12}    MB {2,44}" -f "DB TotalSize", $TotalDBSize ,"#"
                        "{0,-28} {1,12}    MB {2,44}" -f "DB Size", $dbSize ,"#"
                        "{0,-28} {1,15} MB {2,44}" -f "DB UsedSpace", $DbUsedSpace ,"#"
                        "{0,-28} {1,17:p} {2,45}" -f "DB Usage", $DBUsageP ,"#"
                        "{0,-28} {1,12}    MB {2,44}" -f "Log Size", $LogSize ,"#"
                        "{0,-28} {1,15} MB {2,44}" -f "Log UsedSpace", $logUsedSpace ,"#"
                        "{0,-28} {1,17:p} {2,45}" -f "Log Usage", $LogUsageP,"#"
                        "{0,-28}{1,64}" -f "##","#"
                        "############################################################################################"
                        $logstring  =  $Server.Name + ";" + $Db.Name + ";" + $TotalDBSize + ";" + $dbSize + ";" + $LogSize  + ";" + $DbUsedSpace  + ";" +  $LogUsedSpace        
                        Out-File -FilePath $reportcsv -InputObject $logstring -Append
                        }
                }
            }
            
        }

        
    "{0,-28}{1,64}" -f "##","#"
    "{0,-28}{1,64}" -f "##","#"
```

Actually the text output is like this:

```
> ##                                                                                         #
> ####### S E R V E R   N A M E              server0                               ########   
> ##                                                                                         #
> ############################################################################################
> #######  DB SIZE REPORT for DATABASE                                            db1 ###
> ##                                                                                         # DB TotalSize                         1152    MB                                            #  DB TotalSize                         1152    MB                                            # DB Size                              1024    MB                                            # DB UsedSpace                             202 MB                                            # DB Usage                                17,53%                                             # Log Size                              128    MB                                            # Log UsedSpace                           2,27 MB                                            # Log Usage                                1,77%                                             #
> ##                                                                                         #
> ############################################################################################
```

I need to modify it so that I can report (with mail message) only the databases that has the `$DBUsageP` value above 90%.

For that DB I would want to retrieve:

- `$Server.Name`
- `$db.Name`
- `$DBUsageP`

I think that I need a condition in the foreach statement for catch and store `$DBUsageP` value >90%, but I don't know how.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) Give us a question we can actually answer. What *specific* part is it you need help with? What isn't working with with you have?

Comment: @Larnu, Hello Larnu (sorry!), script works, I need your help to modify it to retrive only the informations that I've indicated: $Server.Name; $db.Name; $DBUsageP, without compromising the rest of code

Comment: Ｌａｒｎｕ not *Ｌａｍｕ*...

Comment: Answering how you need to help by saying "I need help" doesn't tell me anything extra. If you only want specific information, only consume that specific information. Like i asked, what specific part? What isn't working with what you have?

Comment: @Larnu, I've edited the answer, does that make it more clear?

Comment: Sounds like you’re asking someone to do the modification work for you. You should do the work, we can help if you have issues.

Comment: @Doug Maurer Hi Doug Maurer, absolutely not! I need only a tip just like that of @Theo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the stuff you want in a variable like in a List:

```
$over90List = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]
```

And add these final lines in the `default` block:

```
if ($DBUsageP -gt 0.9) {
    $over90List.Add([PsCustomObject]@{
        Server   = $Server.Name
        DataBase = $Db.Name
        Usage    = '{0:p}' -f $DBUsageP
    })
}
```

Then you will have an array of objects in `$over90List` to convert into HTML table with [ConvertTo-Html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html) or use as plain-text with `|Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` to put in your email.

Comment: Hi Theo! Thanks! Unfortunately `$DBUsageP` is an INT not a percentage number... in your code the "assumption" of numbers has achieved with `'{0} %' -f $DBUsageP` ?

Comment: In the code of my ex-colleague, I think that the "conversion" to percentage number was performed by "`:p`":
`"{0,-28} {1,17:p} {2,45}" -f "DB Usage", $DBUsageP ,"#"`;
Right?

Comment: @ilRobby Well, you can use any formatting you want, including `{0:p}`

Comment: Theo, the PsCustomObject seems not capture any data... If I set the variable `**$result** = foreach ($Server in $icmDBServers) { .. }`, it contains only the value of other instructions...

Comment: The last value of `$DBUsageP` is 0,852874509803922 (85%) (`$DBUsageP.GetType().FullName: System.Double`)
There are many db over 90%...

Comment: @ilRobby Please see my edit. In this case the loop outputs more than just the PsCustomObject, so now it uses a List object to store db info if usage is more than 90%. Also, i now treat $DBUsageP as double.